# XML Query Select After Date

Tags: xml, date, event-log

I've been browsing around various forums trying to figure out how to restrict Windows Event Log XML queries to a specific date range, but it seems that XML doesn't play very well with it.  The query I have set up is:

```
<QueryList>

<Query Id="0" Path="Application">

<Select Path="Application">

*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Folder Redirection']

and (Level=2)]]

</Select>

</Query>

</QueryList>
```

Basically I'm just trying to find out how to limit the query to x amount of days ago and forward.  I'm trying to find computers with the above error that may present a problem, and if they get flagged for an error from a year ago or something, that doesn't really help me.

Can anyone give me a little direction on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">
      *[System[Provider[@Name='Application Hang'] and (Level=2) and (TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000])]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

This would limit it to those created in the last day (i.e. the last 86,400,000 milliseconds).  I changed the provider name to `Application Hang` since I don't have any errors to test against for `Microsoft-Windows-Folder Redirection`, but you could certainly change it back to that.

If you need to go back further than one day, use the formula to get milliseconds:

`(days) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = (milliseconds)`

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996910(VS.85).aspx#limitations

Comment: Awesome, that worked wonders.  One question, as a fledgling at XML, what does the `&lt;=` represent exactly?

Comment: In XML, `<`, `>`, and `&` are special characters that have to be encoded.  `&lt;` represents the less than sign, so `&lt;=` gets decoded to `<=`.  This is very similar to HTML if you have experience with that.  If you just put `<=`, it would invalidate the XML (it'd look like you started opening a new tag without closing the previous one).